# Google Analytics reports no active users on site even though tag properly implemented

Tags: google-analytics

According to the [Google Tag Assistant](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tag-assistant-by-google/kejbdjndbnbjgmefkgdddjlbokphdefk?hl=en) Chrome extension, Google Analytics is properly implemented on this [site](http://circ-ccrm.ca/). However, when I log into Google Analytics, it reports 0 active users on the site. What might account for this issue?

EDIT: A single user was tracked 6 hours after the code was added but I still cannot see anything in real-time nor do I know if other users were missed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would check a number of things in the following order:

**Use of correct Google Analytics (GA) account and web property:** 
The GA tag is sending data to the web property with ID `UA-109633103-1`. Ensure that you are accessing the view from the right account `UA-109633103` and web property `UA-109633103-1`.

**Wait up to 48 hours for new accounts:** If you just recently created the account, you may need to wait up to 48 hours to see the first pieces of your data.

**Check the filters applied to your view:** Your view may have include or exclude filters that are excluding the hits from your testing.

Comment: I am accessing the correct account. I don't see why I would have to wait 24 hours for real-time data to work. There are no filters applied to any view as the account was just created.

Comment: It's a quirk of Google Analytics - I've seen some new accounts take up to 48 hours to start showing data even in real-time reporting.

Comment: I'm skeptical of this explanation. I've set up many sites and I've never seen this before. Furthermore, it doesn't really make sense. Why would it take 48 hours for real-time reporting to start?

Comment: I stand corrected. It seems that after about 48 hours, the real-time reporting is now working. Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: If you edit your answer to say "Wait 48 hours for new accounts", I will upvote it and mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: @zgall1 Yes, there's no logical explanation for it as its not documented, but this is what I've seen from experience.

Comment: Do you need a view for it to work? I just added the script tag and it's not working yet

Comment: Yes, you need at least one view in order to view the collected data